# Is it possible to prevent microphone from picking up music I play on computer?

Tags: sound

For example, when I talk to someone on Skype or Facebook messenger, he/she can hear the music I'm listening to on youtube, even though I play it through headphones, not speakers. Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge: No. If you play music and your microphone 'hears' it, it will be heard on skype.

Comment: Well, actually, the microphone shouldn't pick up the music, because I'm using headphones. If I have a friend next to me, he will not hear the music...

Comment: I can still hear the music from my own headphones across the room, if i listen carefully. But, if the music is heard perfectly via skype, then it probably is a settings issue. Skype's settings, or the Unity Sound Settings.

Comment: File a bug report against skype and try using jack (jack will likely give finer grained control of input / oputput)

Comment: To test whether the microphone itself is actually picking up the sound as opposed to your computer picking it up even though no music is going to your physical microphone: 1) Install a recording program that only records what is inputted through your external microphone 2) Play the music through your headphones but make sure you keep completely quiet 3) Play back the recording to yourself and if it plays back no music, and yet the Skype call still hears music, then we know it's an inside technical program rather than you just having a microphone better than your ears.